# Как сгладить результат "шумной" функции?

Tags: генетический-алгоритм

Есть некоторая сложная и чувствительная функция (с небольшими рандомами внутри и заметно реагирующая на изменение входных параметров, даже на сотые доли процента) зависящая от 10 параметров. Нужно найти оптимальное сочетание значений параметров, при котором результат будет максимален.

Пробую использовать для этого генетический алгоритм. В целом результат неплохой, но кажется есть проблема - найденные параметры очень чувствительны к незначительым изменениям. Например, отклонение в значении одного параметра на сотые доли процента способно ухудшить итоговый результат на несколько процентов. Другими словами, результат выполнения функции очень "неровный", "шумный".

Подозреваю, что преодолеть эту проблему можно только путем увеличения числа прогонов функции (с мелкими изменениями во входных данных), чтобы все "неровности" результатов функции были усреднены/сглажены "количеством". Верный ли это путь?